# Find the missing number in sequence

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence, puzzle

I assure you this is not assignment or homework or any submission topic
I want to prepare logic to solve the missing number in series problem.

Lets say, to start with, **the triangle missing number problem.**

I want to build logic to find the missing number in the sequence.

I want the community to suggest what should be my approach.

From what i could evaluate is i will be needing to perform permutation of predefined functions to find the solution to it.

Please check [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/puzzles/missing-number-1.html) for example.

Comment: I think we need more details. You want to find the solution: I am not sure this is doable without more information than it is provided on the puzzle. Do you want to know whether your answer matches a provided answer require the answer or the rule that generated the answer? I think I've seen some missing number puzzles with more than one possible answer.

Comment: Hello Santos, you can check for link given in question which will provide more clarity

Comment: I see. If I had to tackle that, I'd devise combinations/permutations of functions as you've mentioned. Please note that there is no guarantee that there will be a simple solution to the puzzles, and there is also no guarantee that your permutations will solve the puzzle. In that example the functions are quite simple, but even so a brute-force approach may not be able to solve it in _reasonable_ time. Let's also hope that there are no puzzles which uses functions like mod or trigonometric ones :-)